# What is the difference between *x=i and x=&i

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between `*x=i` and `x=&i`?

Code:

```
int i=2;
int *x;

*x=i; //what is the difference between this...
x=&i; //...and this??

//Also, what happens when I do these? Not really important but curious.
x=i;
*x=*i;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `*x=i; //what is the difference between this...`

This assigns the value of `i` to an integer stored at the address pointed to by `x`

> `x=&i; //...and this??`

This assigns the address of `i` to `x`.

Note that in your example `x` is unassigned, so the behavior of `*x=i` is undefined.

Here is a better illustration:

```
int i = 2, j = 5;
printf("%d %d\n", i, j); // Prints 2 5
int *x = &j;
*x = i;
printf("%d %d\n", i, j); // Prints 2 2
```

Comment: @ritratt After that, the behaviour of `*x=i` is still undefined because you're not allowed to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: value of j changed without directly accessing the variable j. Mind blown.

Comment: Hey btw, are you sure it is `int *x = &j;` and not `int *x; x=&j`?

Comment: @ritratt The latest version of the compiler should allow both; I tried this syntax on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/UNfTv)) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Ok i was just making sure what operation you were doing there.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i=2;
int *x;

*x=i; // x is not initialized, this is undefined behavior
x=&i; // this assigns the address of i to x
```

and

```
*x=&i; // is invalid C. You cannot assign a pointer to an
       // integer without an explicit conversion.
```

Answer (score 2):

`*x=i` changes the value stored in the memory location pointed to by `x` to be equal to the value stored in `i`.

`x=&i` changes the memory location `x` is pointing to to `i`'s memory location.

`x=i` is wrong. You will most likely get a segfault.

`*x=*i` is wrong. You cannot dereference `i`, because `i` is not a pointer.

`*x=&i` (actually, more properly, `*x=(int)&i`) will store the memory location of `i` as an integer in the memory location pointed to by `x`.

Answer (score 1):

`*x=i;` dereferences the pointer `x` and assigns `i`.

`x=&i` makes the pointer `x` point at the variable `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`*x = i` changes the value stored at the address which is stored in `x`. In your case, unedited, that will crash, because the address `x` is  likely junk, possibly `NULL`. You would need a `malloc()` or `new` or something.

`x = &i` changes the address stored in `x`, so that is is the address of the variable `i`. This is perfectly safe in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you say

```
*x = i
```

You're saying: make the variable x points to the value i.
When you say

```
x = &i
```

You're saying make the address x points to the address of i.
And I guess you should be able to figure the other ones out by yourself!

Answer (score 1):

`*x = i`
This actually assigns the value of `i` to the memory location pointed to by `x`.

`x = &i`
This assigns the address of variable `i` to a pointer variable `x`. `x` should be a pointer.

When you do `x = i`, this will give you a runtime error, as you are trying to erroneously assign an address(which in this case is `2`) which does not belong to the address space of your process. To successfully do this, `i` should also be a pointer and must point to an address which is in your address space.

When you do `*x = *i`, in your case will again give an error. If `i` is a pointer, then the address pointed to by `x` will get the value present at the address pointed to by `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`*x = i` assigns 2 to the memory address pointed to by x.  Note that this would probably crash because x hasn't been initialized to a memory address via malloc or an assignment to a buffer or address of a stack variable.

`x = &i` assigns the pointer `x` to the address of variable `i`.

`x = i` would assign the pointer `x` to the value of `2`, which would most likely point to an invalid memory address and would require a cast.

`*x = *i` would depend on the current value of `x`.  And since `i` is not a pointer you cannot dereference it.

`*x = &i` would write the address of `i` to the memory address pointed to by x, which would depend on the code preceding it.  It would likely crash if you didn't assign x to a valid address.

Some of these calls would require a cast to be syntactically correct.